# Get ID of randomly generated element

Tags: button, dynamic, getelementbyid

I have a very basic understanding of coding. I'm using a program called SpreadsheetWEB to make web form calculators. It has a function that allows you to use Javascript to modify things you've created using their software. Long story short, they've changed their software rendering my custom function useless. I inserted my custom code into the "Page Onload" portion of their program as follows:

```
<script language="javaScript">
{
document.getElementById('btn_Next').style.opacity=0;
document.getElementById('btn_Next').style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)';
document.getElementById('btn_Next').click();
}
</script>
```

This worked perfectly when the button itself was statically named btn_Next. However, the newest version of their software is now dynamically generating the ID for the button. Therefore, I need to modify my code to get the randomly generated button ID so that I can perform the above functions on it.

I know this is all goofy, but it's what my company is insisting that we work with, so there's no good way to dig deep on any of the code to build this correctly. If it's at all helpful, here's the output of the new button based on the below code (as you can see it shows next):

Next

Which is based on this code:

```
<span id="ccid_FormOutputéC1288éV1289éc1323" class="VSJS_InputBase" style="position: absolute; width: 82px; height: 19px; left: 0px; top: 27px; line-height: normal; z-index: 3;">

<a id="FormOutputéC1288éV1289éc1323" class="VSJS_JButton" type="BUTTON" style="width: 80px; height: 17px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block; cursor: pointer; background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(221, 221, 221), rgb(187, 187, 187)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">

<span style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 1px; width: 70px; border: medium none; -moz-user-select: none;">Next</span>
```

The value after the "a id=" I believe is the ID of the button, as it changes every time, and when I inspect with Firebug, it points to the above cluster.

I tried to getElements by class and by type, but this didn't work for me. I'm sure it's because there are multiple similar elements.

Thank you in advance for your time assisting me with this issue I am having.

Comment: what are the odds its the only button with class="VSJS_JButton" on it

Comment: Very good, but I did try to modify my original code from getElementByID to getElementByClassName and then used that name class. However, I didn't change it to getElementsByClassName (Element vs. Elements (plural)), is that what I did wrong? I'll go test now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id
```

try this line here.
also learn jquery

Comment: I'm not at all a programmer, but I've been forced to learn this program (and a bit of code) so that my company can begin to automate their Excel models for clients. I appreciate your assistance. Where would I add that line?

Comment: that is the id add it were required.

Comment: Well, either I'm an idiot, or there's something else preventing this from working. I modified my code where btn_Next was the old ID, and the new ID is what you told me it was, so that my code looked as follows: 

    <script language="javaScript">

    {


document.getElementById('$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id').style.opacity=0;

document.getElementById('$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id').style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)';
    
document.getElementById('$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id').click();
    
}
    
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Modified my code based on the name of the ID that you gave me and placed it where the old id btn_Next was, looks like this (didn't work):

```
<script language="javaScript">
{
document.getElementById('$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id').style.opacity=0;
document.getElementById('$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id').style.filter='alpha(opacity=0)';
document.getElementById('$(".VSJS_JButton").get(0).id').click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: javascript isn't strong enough for that, assign it to a variable and than use that variable without quotes